# Android intent filter data path example

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I tried using the following data in my intent filter:

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="an.example.i.p" android:pathPrefix="t" />
```

Why doesn't the following url trigger it?

```
http://an.example.i.p/t/v2.aspx/chase/a.test.auto
```

Comment: can you please check if this is working for android lollipop? I am stuck there....

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try `android:pathPrefix="/t"`. The `IntentFilter` calls `Uri#getPath` and pass the resulting string to the `PatternMatcher` and `Uri#getPath` returns with the starting `/`.

Comment: WOW. That makes it work with `android:path` too, but that is not how I would read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html). They write `scheme://host:port/path or pathPrefix or pathPattern` which would mean the slash is not part of the path or the pathPrefix. Very annoying inconsistency in the docs. Thanks for figuring it out.